# postfix configuration with SES and attachments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, amazon-web-services, postfix-mta

Background: I've a rails app that sends out transactional and notification emails. 1/20 emails needs to have an attachment.
I'm using postfix, and just setup Amazon Simple Email Service to handle outgoing email.

My understanding is that Amazon SES doesn't currently support sending emails with attachments.

In postfix SES is currently setup as default_transport. Ideally, I'd like to configure it to send out using SES for emails without attachments, and send email without SES for emails with attachments (since SES will reject them anyway).

Is this possible?

If postfix doesn't support this kind of setup, how would I get my rails app to send out emails without attachments using SES and other email without it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon SES now [supports attachments](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2011/07/18/amazon-simple-email-service-announces-attachment-support/).

Comment: This is actually what I was waiting for.

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked nearly a month ago, did you find a solution to your problem?

I think it would be difficult to configure Postfix as you say, I'd suggest two alternatives:

- configure Postfix to deliver the emails normally, in this case you'll be able to send attachments. (You'd not use SES at all).
- leave your Postfix configuration as is, and instead of using attachments you can upload the file somewhere (maybe on S3 since you're using AWS) and post the link in the email. (You'd use only SES).